# Using class in App_code - Finding controls on the page that uses that class

Tags: c#, class, app-code

Hope this will be understandable. Going to simplify the code alot.

I have a Master page, then i have Default.aspx.
In this Default page i have the following.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH_Main" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Ok, so i have a class in the App_Code folder.
Lets say that on page_load on default.aspx i start a function that is called "Populate_Content". I start it with giving it two parameters, the Panel which the items should be at and a ID to select from db.
So it goes like this `Populate_Content(Panel1, 4)`

The function selects from the db and at runtime makes Linkbuttons and adding them to the Panel1, it also gives them a eventhandler for the click event.

The problem is that I'm trying to get the "Populate_Content" function to work in the clickevent that is stored in the App_Code folder.
How can i select the control (Panel1) in the class file that is inside the App_Code folder.
I can get the id of the selected linkbutton with this approach

```
//This the class inside App_Code
void description_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = ((LinkButton)sender).ID.ToString();
    //Then i need to do this.. but i need to find the "Panel1" controller
    //Populate_Content("Panel1", id);
}
```

But i need to start the "Populate_Content" in the click event also.
So i need the to find the "Panel1" controler that is in the default.aspx.

I have tried to use the page property on the sender like so. But no go.

```
Page def_page = ((LinkButton)sender).Page;
Panel panel1 = (Panel)def_page.FindControl("Panel1");
```

I though the page property would give me the page where the controller is, i cant find anything about this on google.

Am I doing this wront or is there another way ?

**Edit: This the Populate_content**

```
public void Populate_content(Panel cont, string treenode)
{
var query = from n in dc.Nemanet_Navigations
            where n.UserId == userGuid && n.Nav_pID.ToString() == treenode
            orderby n.Nav_Name
            select n;

foreach (var item in query)
 {
     if (item.Nav_IsFile == true)
     {
         Panel div = new Panel();
         div.CssClass = "BulletDiv";
         cont.Controls.Add(div);

         Image picture = new Image();
         picture.ImageUrl = "~/Icons/Nytt_skjal.png";
         div.Controls.Add(picture);

         div.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

         LinkButton description = new LinkButton();
         description.Text = item.Nav_Name;
         description.ID = item.Nav_ID.ToString();
         description.Click += new EventHandler(description_Click);
         div.Controls.Add(description);


     }

     else if (item.Nav_IsFile == false)
     {
         Panel div = new Panel();
         div.CssClass = "BulletDiv";
         cont.Controls.Add(div);

         Image picture = new Image();
         picture.ImageUrl = "~/Icons/Ny_mappa.png";
         div.Controls.Add(picture);

         div.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

         LinkButton description = new LinkButton();
         description.Text = item.Nav_Name;
         description.ID = item.Nav_ID.ToString();
         description.Click += new EventHandler(description_Click);

         div.Controls.Add(description);
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: can you show the code that wires up the event that then calls the Populate_Content method..
You may be able to use a anon delegate with a closure so the event knows the panel that was passed in rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: I have edited the question, if you are talking about the Page_Load event then its just runs the event "Populate_Content(Panel1, id)"